# Pygame: Why won't window appear?

Tags: python, pygame, window, screen, draw

I've been trying to make a basic pokemon-esque game with my son. It has been a rather ad-hoc learning experience.

I've gotten most things to work one way or another, but the following code doesn't seem to want to cooperate. All that should be happening is the screen appearing, filled white, with the two 'pokemon' being draw upon it. As is, the screen pops up for a split second, then closes. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

```
import pygame
import random
import sys



Boomeroo = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\19168\\Desktop\\1stgame\\img\\Boomeroo.png")
Caterpetal = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\19168\\Desktop\\1stgame\\img\\Caterpetal.png")


class Pokemon():
   def __init__(self, x, y, name):
    
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.img = None
    

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))

class Playerpoke(Pokemon):
    def __init__(self, x, y, name):
        super().__init__(x, y, name)
    
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 100
        self.img = Caterpetal
        self.name = "Caterpetal"



class Wild(Pokemon):
    def __init__(self, x, y, name):
        super().__init__(x, y, name)
   
        self.x = 280
        self.y = 380
        self.pic = Boomeroo
        self.name = "Boomeroo"



class Game():
    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()
    

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))

        self.player = Playerpoke(self,50,100)
        self.wild = Wild(self,280,380)

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()



    def redraw():

        self.player.draw(self.screen)
        self.wild.draw(self.screen)
        self.screen.fill((255,255,255))
        pygame.display.update()
    

    def main(self):
        running = True
        while running:
    
            self.redraw()
            self.clock.tick(60)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Where do you call the `main` method?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `main` method. Create a `Game` instance and invoke `main`:

```py
game = Game()
game.main()
pygame.quit()
```